# Annoying/confusing Wordpress memory limit exhausted

Tags: php, multisite, memory

I'm setting up a staging site on the same server as a live site. Wordpress 7.1, PHP 7.2. Site is a multisite install I've been working with for years.

Everything is identical apart from domain names.

php.ini memory limit is deliberately very high 500MB

Apache config:

```
php_value memory_limit 256M  
php_value register_globals off  
php_value max_execution_time 600  
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M  
php_value post_max_size 64M
```

wp-config.php contains these lines:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

.htaccess file does not include any lines dealing with memory limits.

Everything is identical to the live site, or has a higher memory limit.

Live site works fine.

Staging site, when visiting /wp-login.php throws an out of memory error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 19628820 bytes) in /path/to/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2888
```

268435456 bytes is obviously equal to a very low memory limit of 32MB.

Given that the staging and live site are almost identical, any idea what's going on?

As you can imagine, this is a pretty frustrating error!

Comment: Are the plugins and themes the same for both production and staging?

Comment: are you sure? online calculators suggest that 268,435,456 bytes is actually 256MB not 32. 32MB is actually only 4,194,304 bytes. Eitherway that's a truly massive memory requirement, I would be concerned by any site that uses more than 64 or even 32 for a standard page load

Comment: Also a max execution limit of 600 allows for a 10 minute page generation time, that's huge. Eitherway there's no code in your question, I don't see how this can be answered with the info available short of having direct access to the filesystem and server

Comment: Huh ... I was using Google to do my byte-MB conversion and it was clearly hugely wrong. Ok thanks.

Comment: have you verified this in php info page?